# Desserialization of + (plus) in Spring Request Param

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have a simple HTTP GET request like this:

http://localhost:8080/search?page=0&size=20&sort=id,asc&description=1+3

And a RestController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<TestEntity>> search(Pageable pageable, @RequestParam("description") String description) {

    Page<TestEntity> page = service.search(pageable, description);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page);
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .body(page.getContent());

}
```

But the value of `@RequestParam` "description" is getting "1 3".

What am I doing wrong?

Or what should I do so that signals like "+" are deserialized to "+" in the Spring `@RequestParam`?

This is my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <project.http.version>1.23.0</project.http.version>
    <project.oauth.version>1.23.0</project.oauth.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: How do you send the request? in browser or using tool/command?

Comment: I'm using Angular 7 (HttpClient).

Comment: Update my answer, For angular use `HttpUrlEncodingCodec.encodeValue("1 3")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything is as expected. As per [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) in URL encoding `+` is a reserved character. As per point 2.2. Reserved Characters:

> If a reserved character is found in a URI component and no delimiting role is known for that character, then it must be interpreted as representing the data octet corresponding to that character's encoding in US-ASCII.

To use `+` as a value you need to encode it as `%2B` as explained in [Percent-encoding reserved characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters). This will make your URL:

http://localhost:8080/search?page=0&size=20&sort=id,asc&description=1%2B3

Do note that sometimes Spring is inconsistent when it comes to `+` handling e.g. [SPR-16860 Spring is inconsistent in the encoding/decoding of URLs](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16860) bug.

Comment: RFC3986 does not specify `+` to be decoded to space. On the contrary, it states, that "If a reserved character is found in a URI component and no delimiting role is known for that character, then it must be interpreted as representing the data octet corresponding to that character's encoding in US-ASCII."

Answer (score 3):

You are missing [URL Encoding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) which isn't related to deserialization,

> `+` is encoded by %2B

When you send HTTP request you should encode your parameters values, in your case `+` should be replaced with `%2B`:

```
http://localhost:8080/search?page=0&size=20&sort=id,asc&description=1%2B3
```

For angular use [HttpUrlEncodingCodec](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpUrlEncodingCodec) `encodeValue(value: string)`